# Scraping a WP table with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a table to make data analysis. But I think, I'm struggling finding the table class. It return that my object has no attribute 'tbody'.
Any help would be appriciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

url = 'https://prosettings.net/rocket-league-pro-camera-settings-controller-list/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper'}).tbody
print(table)
```

In the dev tools this is what I can find about this table :

```
<div id="table_1_wrapper" class="wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper">
```

```
<table id="table_1" class="responsive display nowrap data-t data-t wpDataTable dataTable" style="" data-described-by="table_1_desc" data-wpdatatable_id="61" role="grid" aria-describedby="table_1_info">
```

Comment: What is the *relevant* portion of the HTML you are scraping?

Comment: I would like to scrap entire first table from this website https://prosettings.net/rocket-league-pro-camera-settings-controller-list/.

Comment: usually pages don't use `<tbody>` in HTML but browser may show it in `DevTools`

Comment: I don't see class `wpDataTablesWrapper` in HTML - there is only `wpDataTables`

Comment: It don't work either with this class : 
    `table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wpDataTables'}).tbody
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'`

Comment: if you search `<div>` then use `find('div')`, not `find('table')`

Comment: as I said before - browser may shows `tbody` but `BS` works with pure HTML which doesn't have `<tbody>` and you can't find it .

Comment: So what should I use to scrap this ?

Comment: `table = soup.find('table',{'id':'table_1'}).tbody`I was able to get it with this.

Comment: @r-beginners You are the man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `table` with classes `wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper`, but with class `wpDataTable` (without `s` at the end)

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wpDataTable'}).tbody
```

and this gives me `tbody`

---

**EDIT:** as @r-beginners mentioned in comment above you can also use `id`

```
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'table_1'}).tbody
```

---

**BTW:** If you see in browser `table` with classes `wpDataTables wpDataTablesWrapper` then probably server sends different HTML for different devices/browsers and you may have to use `User-Agent` in requests to simulate your browser. As default `requests` sends something like `Python/x.x` in header  `User-Agent`

Comment: I tried it. This is the output: 
`table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wpDataTables'}).tbody AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'`

Comment: it has to be `wpDataTable` without  `s` at the end

Comment: I added @r-beginners version too.